# Can I safely eat uncooked raw chicken that has been in my freezer over a year?

Tags: food-safety, freezing, raw-meat

Can I safely eat raw uncooked chicken that has been in my freezer since April 2018 (over a year)?

Comment: I would advise against it. Curious, why would you want to eat raw chicken ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't eat it raw.  However, while the quality has likely degraded, it can be cooked and eaten safely if it was handled properly before freezing, and has remained in the freezer since.

Comment: You can cut it up for chicken chili or something. That should rehydrate, and get any nasty freexer taste out.